# How to pull in data by using a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to pull in data from our API with a `data-` html trick.. I can call the data directly and it load just fine. But when i try to get the data variable from the data attribute it won't work.

Is there something flawed in my code?

**i.e.**

```
<span id="totalBalanceBTC" data-api-user-getbalance="totalBalance">--</span>
```

```
function dataAPI() {
    let balanceUrl = 'https://api.example.io/v1/user/getbalance/username';
    let balanceApiData = getApiData(balanceUrl);

    $('[data-api-user-getbalance]').each(function (){

      let dataUserBalance = $(this).data("api-user-getbalance");
      let data = balanceApiData.dataUserBalance;

        // WORKS
        $(this).html(balanceApiData.totalBalance);

        // DOES NOT WORK
        $(this).html(balanceApiData.dataUserBalance);

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**  jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) drops the `data-` prefix and **converts the remaining hyphenated string to camelCase**, using the dashes as delimiters. It should be:

```
let dataUserBalance = $(this).data("apiUserGetbalance");
```

**2.** To access an object property using a variable, you'll need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). Otherwise you're trying to get the property `"dataUserBalance"`, which doesn't exist.

```
let data = balanceApiData[dataUserBalance];
```

```js
const balanceApiData = { totalBalance: 500 };
const $elem = $("#totalBalanceBTC");

let dataUserBalance = $elem.data("apiUserGetbalance");
let data = balanceApiData[dataUserBalance];

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="totalBalanceBTC" data-api-user-getbalance="totalBalance"></span>
```